# is it required to install nginx and docker together?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I have a PHP/Laravel project and a server in digital ocean I was a able to run locally my project using docker/docker-compose, now in the server I installed docker, now my question is do I need to install nginx in my server? because the docker project has already nginx and is it exposing the port 80

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.prod.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 80:80      
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**nginx.prod.dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
ADD ./nginx/default.prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
ADD ./src/ /var/www/html
```

is it required to install ngnix in the server? now, what if I have to have another site in the same server? do I just expose the 80 port?, is it going to have conflicts? my question is because in another servers I installed nginx that have differents projects, but using docker is a little bit different, thanks

Comment: You can use one nginx container for all of your websites. As you know there is a `sitename` option in web server (like nginx) config files that you could use it to separate received requests to different ports. You only need to have different config files for your websites.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to run your project on server.

1. use docker and nginx server only for local development and deploy the code without installing the docker on server and configuring your laravel project directly.
2. Create docker image and deploy it on server for that purpose you will need to install docker on your server and every you push your code to server, you will need to create a new image and deploy it on server.